# How can I improve response query time on Magento PWA with Magento 2.4.3 backend? low response network speed on production with Magento PWA

Tags: magento2.4.3, graphql, pwa, pwa-studio, magento-graphql

i'm currently developing a Magento PWA front with a Magento 2.4.3 store on backend. Thing is, when testing on production, and specially Category pages, sometimes the response time of some queries is to high and its making the store very slow. Im using Varnish so the response time may vary but when its slow, well, its slow. That reflects on lighthouse performance scores too.

Are there some specifics about magento-graphql caching that I should be aware of, and also, are this problems solved on 2.4.4 ? Thanks!

Comment: Please consider posting last 100 lines of your Magento Slow Query Log.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.